# pushing array into serializeArray send by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, serializearray

I use this code for my form

```
var formData = $("#form").serializeArray();
```

now I want to push an array into formData variable like this

```
[{"name":"xxxx"},{"name":"xxxx"}]
```

or push the array to object of the formData

Update: I want to send the data via ajax to server

any solution?

Comment: `serializeArray()` returns an array, so normal array operations like push or concat will work, along with all the details that those methods involve.

Comment: can  you give me any example? I tried many solutions but I got nothing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5zL1cpod/  Fairly simple test case to run.  Your question is primarily about how to push an array to an existing array, where there should already be duplicate questions about on the site.

Comment: there is a problem,  I send the data via ajax to server and I see nothing data have sent it says undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very well I answer my question, forget about the serializeArray() so

```
    var formData = {};
    formData['X1'] = [];
    item1 = {}
    item1 ["name"] = "XXX";
    formData['X1'].push(item1);
```

the result is:

```
{[{"name":"XXX"},{"name":"XXX"}]}
```

then send formData  via ajax, it's easy, isn't it?